# Jupyter Notebook: OSError: "/bin/PHSshell" shell not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm dealing with a project using lesion network mapping with symptoms.
While I was trying to "Set up metadata dataframe and rename files to BIDS format", the code was like:

```
env["meta_df"] = preprocessing.init_meta_df(env["lesion_type"], env["lesions"], env["project_path"])

preprocessing.save_env(env)
```

And the result showed:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-e78bda9b0228> in <module>
----> 1 env["meta_df"] = preprocessing.init_meta_df(env["lesion_type"], env["lesions"], env["project_path"])
      2 preprocessing.save_env(env)

~/.conda/envs/nimlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nimlab/preprocessing.py in init_meta_df(lesion_type, lesions, project_path)
    637             )
    638 
--> 639     ipython.system(f"datalad save -d {project_path} -m 'Added original files'")
    640 
    641     # Reformat filenames

~/.conda/envs/nimlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py in system_piped(self, cmd)
    633                 self.user_ns['_exit_code'] = system(cmd)
    634         else:
--> 635             self.user_ns['_exit_code'] = system(self.var_expand(cmd, depth=1))
    636 
    637     # Ensure new system_piped implementation is used

~/.conda/envs/nimlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py in system(self, cmd)
    155                 child = pexpect.spawnb(self.sh, args=['-c', cmd]) # Pexpect-U
    156             else:
--> 157                 child = pexpect.spawn(self.sh, args=['-c', cmd])  # Vanilla Pexpect
    158             flush = sys.stdout.flush
    159             while True:

~/.conda/envs/nimlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py in sh(self)
     64             self._sh = pexpect.which(shell_name)
     65             if self._sh is None:
---> 66                 raise OSError('"{}" shell not found'.format(shell_name))
     67 
     68         return self._sh

OSError: "/bin/PHSshell" shell not found
```

So what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your login shell is not available to the process executing Jupyter Notebook.

I experienced a similar error (`OSError: "/usr/bin/zsh" shell not found`) because I changed my login shell to Zsh on my host system and executed Jupyter Notebook in a toolbox container that did not have `/usr/bin/zsh`.

Here's what I would suggest to try if you can modify the `kernel.json` file:

1. Locate the `kernel.json` file by running `jupyter kernelspec list`.

Example output:

```bash
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  julia-1.2    /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia-1.2
  python3      /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

2. Add the following lines to the `kernel.json` file with your editor of choice:

```
"env": {
  "SHELL": "/usr/bin/bash"
}
```

Instead of `"/usr/bin/bash"`, you may also use `"sh"` (this will depend on the feature requirements imposed by your code).

Example output:

```bash
$ vi /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 },
 "env": {
   "SHELL": "/usr/bin/bash"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matthias, on that. Any ideas on how to add the configuration to all `kernel.json`